# Why django rest api root does not list classic endpoints

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have registerd some of my endpoints through routers and written others in classic style, by classic style I mean that they are not registerd through router but directly written in path. Now problem is that api root lists only the endpoints that are registered through router and i want both to be listed.

app/views.py

```
from uuid import UUID

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

from event.models import Event
from event.serializers import EventSerializer
from food_album.models import FoodAlbums
from food_album.serializers import FoodAlbumsSerializer
from restaurant.models import RestaurantProfile
from restaurant.serializers import RestaurantProfileSerializer
from .serializers import *

customer_favourites = {
    0: [RestaurantProfile, RestaurantProfileSerializer],
    1: [Event, EventSerializer],
    2: [FoodAlbums, FoodAlbumsSerializer]
}


class CustomerProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = CustomerProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'public_id'

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['create', 'update']:
            return CustomerProfileCreateSerializer
        return self.serializer_class


class RewardTypesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = RewardTypes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RewardTypesSerializer
    lookup_field = 'public_id'


class RewardActionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = RewardActions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RewardActionsSerializer
    lookup_field = 'public_id'


class ReportItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
       A viewset that provides the standard actions
       """
    queryset = ReportItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportItemSerializer
    lookup_field = 'public_id'


class CustomerFavouritesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
       A viewset that provides the standard actions
       """

    serializer_class = CustomerFavouritesSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    lookup_field = 'public_id'

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(customer=self.request.user.customer)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.customer:
            return CustomerFavourites.objects.filter(customer=user.customer)
        else:
            return None


class UserFeedsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    serializer_class = RestaurantProfileSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request):
        r = RestaurantProfile.objects.all()
        serializer = RestaurantProfileSerializer(r, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class CustomerBookmarkViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def list(self, request, reference_type):
        bookmarks = CustomerFavourites.objects.filter(type=0,
                                                      reference_type=reference_type).values_list(
            'reference_id', flat=True)
        public_ids = [UUID(id_) for id_ in bookmarks]
        r = customer_favourites.get(reference_type)[0].objects.filter(
            public_id__in=public_ids).all()
        serializer = customer_favourites.get(reference_type)[1](r, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class CustomerFavouriteViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def list(self, request, reference_type):
        favs = CustomerFavourites.objects.filter(type=1,
                                                 reference_type=reference_type).values_list(
            'reference_id', flat=True)
        public_ids = [UUID(id_) for id_ in favs]
        r = customer_favourites.get(reference_type)[0].objects.filter(
            public_id__in=public_ids).all()
        serializer = customer_favourites.get(reference_type)[1](r, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'profile', views.CustomerProfileViewSet,
                base_name='profile')
router.register('reward-actions', views.RewardActionsViewSet, base_name='reward_actions')
router.register('reward-types', views.RewardTypesViewSet, base_name='reward_types')
router.register('report-item', views.ReportItemViewSet, base_name='report_item')
router.register('toggle-favourites', views.CustomerFavouritesViewSet, base_name='toggle_favourites')


urlpatterns = [
    path('customer/', include(router.urls)),
    path('customer/user-feeds/',
         views.UserFeedsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})),
    path('customer/favourites/<int:reference_type>/',
         views.CustomerFavouriteViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    path('customer/bookmarks/<int:reference_type>/',
         views.CustomerBookmarkViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
]
```

Comment: The list is a feature of the router.

Comment: Is that mean **classic endpoints** can not be shown in api root?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append router.urls to the list of existing views as 
    **urlpatterns += router.urls**. For more information, kindly look into - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Comment: Include works. but my points is that router registered endpoints are listed in api root but the other three that i have written in urlpatternes are not listed api root